# Reading files in linux with inotify in php

Tags: php, linux

I need to read a file in linux when changes are made to it and output the contents of the file to php. I read about inotify and i think it's the one i'm looking for. I don't understand it well. do i need to install inotify in linux so i can use inotify in php?.. if possible can you show me a quick example of how i use it in php for reading/tailing a file in php for events that occured in the file?.

Thanks,

Comment: have you checked [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php) or other [google results](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=inotify+php+example&oq=inotify+php&gs_l=hp.3.1.0l2j0i30j0i5i30.43245.43716.1.45079.4.4.0.0.0.0.309.984.0j1j2j1.4.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.D_X4n3ivEe8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=478a4588e0794d6e&biw=1280&bih=882)?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inotify+php?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `shell`/`bash` in PHP:

```
$shell = shell_exec("cat file");
print $shell
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.